# sync large amount of data to s3 (aws)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I need to sync 2.5TB of data from file system to s3 in AWS.

I will use AWS CLI command :

" aws s3 sync . s3://MyBucket "

this command will sync current folder to a bucket called MyBucket in s3.

My Question is:

1) Would it be possible to do it in one go without timeout?

2) What would be the limits/problem I would expect considering amount of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A assume you're talking about a single file, or a few very large files? If so:

1) Yes, the file(s) will be uploaded in small parts so you don't have to worry about that kind of thing.
2) It will take a long time, which is unavoidable. If the upload fails too many times for a given file part, the upload will be aborted.